# How do I mount a new TV antenna to an existing antenna mast?

Tags: mounting, tv-antenna

I would like to mount my new antenna to the side of my existing antenna mast. Is there a device that I can buy that will clamp on to both poles?

Update - With pictures

Picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuAhW.png) is an old antenna mast and I would like to mount my new antenna [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y239T.jpg) to somewhere on the side of the antenna mast.

[image: Antenna mast]

[image: Channel Master 4221HD]

Comment: I don't follow.  The antenna should just mount directly to the mast.  Can you supply a diagram of exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch - I have included pictures of what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Why won't the clamp on the new antenna work as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like http://www.caworldwifi.com/images/T/univantmnt.jpg.  Clamp the bottom to the existing mast (or a leg) with u-bolts.  Then clamp antenna on the "mast" portion of the universal antenna mount?